# How to handle JSV with a comma(,) containing value?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

Assume we have a string as follows:

```
string employeeDetails=[{Id:100,Name:John,Address:#39 ,street ,Country},{Id:101,Name:Brein,Address:#79 ,street ,Country}];
```

This is how i am Deserialising my string.

```
JsvStringSerializer jsv = new JsvStringSerializer();
List<EmploymentDetails> employmentDetails = jsv.DeserializeFromString<List<EmploymentDetails>>(employeeDetails);
```

As a result i am getting each employee address upto first comman 
i.e.,

```
employeeDetail.Address value as "#39" instead of "#39 ,street ,Country"
```

This is happening due to JSV format with comma(,) as separated value.

How to handle this scenarios with JSV in ServiceStack? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSV uses [CSV-style escaping](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#csv-escaping) where any string that requires escaping should be wrapped with **double-quotes**, e.g:

```
Address:"#39 ,street ,Country"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply . Its working fine !! .Is there any another solution where I can go completely with JSV-style rather than CSV-style.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @ANRUpgradedVersion JSV is just JSON with CSV-style escaping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying things .